# window service auto restart existing tomcat service everday

Tags: windows-services, tomcat6

Is there any utility / maybe use window scheduler to auto restart "tomcat6 service" everyday? any guideliness on this?

My tomcat service is installed using javaservice.exe .

Comment: Why do you need to auto restart? If you need it to auto start then set the start-up option of tomcat6 service to Auto in windows services (services.msc).

Comment: no, i want auto restart everyday.  coz web application memory leak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**window scheduler to auto restart "tomcat6 service"**

- First of all create 2 different bat files :

**1. Tomcat_start.bat**

```
@echo off
net Start tomcat6
```

**2. Tomcat_stop.bat**

```
@echo off
net stop tomcat6
```

Reason to create two different `bat` file is: give 1-5 min time to stop service completely otherwise service cannot start.

**Scheduler Image :**
[image]

As you can see in image create two different scheduler, one for stop and one for start.
I have provided 15 min time between stop and start. you can give 3-5 min(this is minimum required time to stop service completely if any heavy load).

**Note:**
1. As you can see in image give `Run with highest Privileges` checked true and also change `Run Whether user is logged on or not`.
2. Set your `bat` file in `actions` tab and set time in `Triggers` tab.

Comment: hi jubin, good answer, but i need to start tomcat if tomcat suddenly crashed or something happens and tomcat goes down. so i want like continously check tomcat is running or not after every 15min to 20 mins if it's not, just start tomcat. If any paid app also there please suggest.. Need for windows server...

Comment: First Check,service starting normally from task scheduler? If that works fine, check time duration between stop and start service. Still face issue then you can add "settings" for restart service with N number of attempts.

Comment: If still face issue contact/hire freelancer/consultant :)

Comment: Thankx @Jubin for your suggestion.. But myself is a developer but i am mobile app developer so server restart task given by my client is not cup of tea so ask here... :) Happy coading...

Comment: you have error code for service failure? from that I can help you more.

Comment: Thank jubin... but one of my co-partner fixed it.. Btw thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule a batch file with:
net stop YourService
net start YourService

Rod

Comment: in this case i would need a way to put the batch file into window schduler and make it auto execute. can elaborate more?

Comment: visit this for a tutorial on using Windows Sheduler.
http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm

Comment: Also fix the memory leak as soon as possible :)

Comment: I did exactly that but sometimes stopping the service just doesn't work. Any advice to work around that?